# How to create walls and up/down/right/left code for maze

Tags: netlogo

I created a border of black patches and the rest of the "walls" of the maze are purple.  How would I code the maze so that it won't walk into the walls?  And also how would you code the up/down/left/right buttons to control the turtle that walks through the maze.  Thanks so much! I tried so much but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find everything you need in this example model in NetLogo Model library

```
(File  => Model Library => Pac- Man
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you find what you need :)